# Using existing instance if constructed with same values

Tags: java, constructor, reference, instance, inner-classes

I have to create a class/constructor which allows the following:

```
Object a = new Object("test");
Object b = new Object("test");

a == b // should be true
```

So Object a and b should not only be the same according to their values but also should use the same reference and reference the same memory.

The constructor should find out if an instance with the given values already exists and if yes just take the reference and point it to the existing object.

Is there some way to get all created instance of a specific class?
Can someone give me a short hint where to start? I have no idea...

Comment: What you are asking for is impossible. There are workarounds.

Comment: >but also should use the same reference and reference the same memory. no they are two differnet object with same value

Comment: Use a factory to create the objects. It can maintain a cache which maps object values => object instances. If there's a cache hit, return the previously created object. If there's a cache miss, construct and return a new object.

Comment: They are located on a separate memory address so they wont be equal

Comment: You might have to start by making your own compiler/JVM... :)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible using plain constructors, as these always entail a memory allocation. Typically, you would use a static factory method in order to have better control over object creation.

Answer (score 1):

Use something similar to the Singleton pattern, but with an Object pool of its own type as a data member, and then go through getInstance() to make new instances.  Within getInstance(), check the pool for matching Object already existing, and if so, just pull a reference to hand back; if not, call the private constructor to make a new one, add it to the pool, and then return it.

```
public class A {
    static ArrayList<A> existingAs =new ArrayList<>();
    private String val;

    private A(String value)
    {
        this.val=value;
    }

    public A getInstance(String value)
    {
        A newA=null;
        for(A a: existingAs)
        {
            if(a.getVal().equals(value))
                return a;
        }

        newA=new A(value);
        existingAs.add(newA);
        return newA;


    }
    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it be bad practice to use an `ArrayList` to store the instances? EDIT: don't worry-- just seen your edit with code :)

Comment: Since you're not often deleting or inserting at an index, I'd think that it wouldn't be too bad, performance-wise.  Most of what you're doing is searching, and ArrayLists are pretty good for that.  
A TreeSet might be a good choice too, given the lack of duplicates, to improve search performance.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifacation :) P.S, `exisitingA` is never instantiated

Comment: d'oh!  (Embarrassing :))

Answer (score 0):

`new` always creates a new instance. You could use a static factory method which internally pools the instances.